# unable to get simple jquery ajax call to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am sure this is very simple, but I am trying to  get a simple jquery ajax call to work. I have two files, index.html and page.html, both in the same directory.

This is the content of index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Ajax call</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ajax call</h1>
    <p><a href="#">Click here to fetch HTML content</a></p>
    <div id="result">

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('a').click(function(){
                $('#result').load('page.html');
            });
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the content of page.html:

```
<strong>Loaded</strong>
```

I am very confused to why this does not work, when I click the link nothing occurs.

Comment: looks about right. Are you doing this on a webserver, like wamp etc. and did you open the console (F12) and check for errors.

Comment: pretty sure if i copy pasted that code to my server it would work. Side-note, you don't need `$(document).ready()` there because the script is located after the element it is targeting. **that won't fix your problem**

Comment: Check your javascript error console and the network tab of your browser tools for the xhr request.

Comment: Try debugging with Firebug or Chrome Developer tools.  I copied your code locally, and it worked for me.  In the 'Network' tab of the developers tools, you should see the network request to get the page.html, or if you don't see it in the network tab, that might be the reason is isn't working.

Comment: Are you sure the file is really named `page.html` and not something else like `page.htm`?

Comment: Oh sorry guys its a problem with my websever

Comment: I bet money that he is not using a web server.

Comment: **Stop using file:// to view webpages.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('a').click(function(){
                $.get("page.html",function(result){
                   $('#result').html(result);
                });
                return false;
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: What's the difference ?

Comment: An explanation of why return false might solve the issue would be good here. return false will keep the click of the link form going off and loading the linked page in addition to the ajax content, which would not be visible as the new page had already loaded.

Comment: This gave the same result.

Comment: @DrCord - there is no linked page. A hash in the href attribute does not load a new page.

Comment: I am aware that a hash in the link is an anchor. The anchor can still cause a page reload.

Comment: The anchor would usually be the element, shortened to `<a>`, and using a hash in the href will not reload the page, in all browsers in existance it will scroll to the top, that's all.